# Parsing a string in Python with variable field sizes

Tags: python

I have This string of length 66. 
`RP000729SP001CT087ET02367EL048TP020DS042MF0220LT9.300000LN4.500000`. Two alphabets (keyword like `RP`) show next is value until the next keyword.

Now I am parsing the string keeping the number of bytes constant between two keywords i.e. 000729 between `RP` and `SP`. And following is the code to parse like that.

```
msgStr = "RP000729SP001CT087ET02367EL048TP020DS042MF0220LT9.300000LN4.500000"

Ppm = msgStr[msgStr.find("RP")+2:msgStr.find("SP")]
Speed = msgStr[msgStr.find("SP")+2:msgStr.find("CT")]
Coolent_temp = msgStr[msgStr.find("CT")+2:msgStr.find("ET")]
ETime = msgStr[msgStr.find("ET")+2:msgStr.find("EL")]
E_load = msgStr[msgStr.find("EL")+2:msgStr.find("TP")]
Throttle_pos = msgStr[msgStr.find("TP")+2:msgStr.find("DS")]
Distance = msgStr[msgStr.find("DS")+2:msgStr.find("MF")]
MAF = msgStr[msgStr.find("MF")+2:msgStr.find("LT")]
Lat = msgStr[msgStr.find("LT")+2:msgStr.find("LN")]
Lon = msgStr[msgStr.find("LN")+2:]

print Ppm, Speed, Coolent_temp, ETime, E_load, Throttle_pos, Distance, MAF, Lat, Lon
```

Output:

```
000729 001 087 02367 048 020 042 0220 9.300000 4.500000
```

Now I want to collect if there are any number of bytes between two keywords. examples are given below

Example No. 1:

```
Example1_msgStr= "RP729SP14CT087ET2367EL48TP20DS42MF0220LT0.000000LN0.000000"
```

Expected Ouput 1:

```
729 14 087 2367 48 20 42 0220 0.000000 0.000000
```

Example No. 2:

```
Example2_msgStr = "RP72956SP134CT874ET02367EL458TP20DS042MF0220LT53.000LN45.00"
```

Expected Ouput 2:

```
72956 134 874 02367 458 20 042 0220 53.000 45.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a regular expression to find variable length matches between two strings:

```
import re
regex = r'RP(\d+)SP'
strings = ['RP729SP14CT087ET2367EL48TP20DS42MF0220LT0.000000LN0.000000',
    'RP72956SP134CT874ET02367EL458TP20DS042MF0220LT53.000LN45.00']
for string in strings:
    match = re.search(regex,string)
    print('Matched:',match.group(1))
```

In the regex the brackets () specify a group to store and \d+ means 1 or more number characters. So the whole regex `RP(\d+)SP` will find a variable length string of numbers between RP and SP.

This shows you how to do one case, you'll need to loop through your delimiters (RP, SP, CT etc. etc.) to capture all the information you want. If the delimiters always come in the same order you can build one enormous regex to capture all the groups at once ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for characters between your delimiters, you can use your code and then turn any of your variables into `bool` type. If the string is not empty it means that there is something in that string and thus it returns True. If the string is empty, it returns False:

```
    msgStr = 'RP000729SP001CT087ET02367EL048TP020DS042MF0220LT9.300000LN4.500000'

    rpm = msgStr[msgStr.find("RP")+2:msgStr.find("SP")]       # Outputs '000729'
    Speed = msgStr[msgStr.find("SP")+2:msgStr.find("CT")]     # Outputs '001'
    coolent_temp = msgStr[msgStr.find("CT")+2:msgStr.find("ET")] # Outputs '087'
    ETime = msgStr[msgStr.find("ET")+2:msgStr.find("EL")]     # '02367'
    e_load = msgStr[msgStr.find("EL")+2:msgStr.find("TP")]    # '048'
    throttle_pos = msgStr[msgStr.find("TP")+2:msgStr.find("DS")] # '020'
    Distance = msgStr[msgStr.find("DS")+2:msgStr.find("MF")]  # Outputs '042'
    MAF = msgStr[msgStr.find("MF")+2:msgStr.find("LT")]       # Outputs '0220'
    Lat = msgStr[msgStr.find("LT")+2:msgStr.find("LN")]       # Outputs '9.300000'
    Lon = msgStr[msgStr.find("LN")+2:]                        # Outputs '4.500000'

    bool(rpm)           # Outputs True
    bool(Speed)         # Outputs True
    bool(coolent_temp)  # Outputs True
    bool(ETime)         # Outputs True
    bool(e_load)        # Outputs True
    bool(throttle_pos)  # Outputs True
    bool(Distance)      # Outputs True
    bool(MAF)           # Outputs True
    bool(Lat)           # Outputs True
    bool(Lon)           # Outputs True
```

You could check several fields being not empty at the same time:

```
    all_filled = bool(rpm) and bool(Speed) and bool(coolent_temp) and \
    bool(ETime) and bool(e_load) and bool(throttle_pos) and bool(Distance) \
    and bool(MAF) and bool(Lat) and bool(Lon)
```

The way your code is set, if you try it with `msgStr1` you get already the separation you desired:

```
Example1_msgStr= "RP729SP14CT087ET2367EL48TP20DS42MF0220LT0.000000LN0.000000"
# ... your code ...
print (rpm, Speed, coolent_temp, ETime, e_load, throttle_pos, Distance, MAF, Lat, Lon)
#> 729 14 087 2367 48 20 42 0220 0.000000 0.000000

Example2_msgStr= "RP72956SP134CT874ET02367EL458TP20DS042MF0220LT53.000LN45.00"
# ... your code ...
print (rpm, Speed, coolent_temp, ETime, e_load, throttle_pos, Distance, MAF, Lat, Lon)
#> 72956 134 874 02367 458 20 042 0220 53.000 45.00
```